# React native force update

Tags: react-native

I made an android app bu using react native and ı uploaded it to google play store. If I make the upgrade version of this app, when I upload it to google play store, I force the User to update this  app. That is completed succesfully, how ever when The User open the google play store link of this app, they do not see UPDATE . They just see remove or open app in google play store, altough the version is upgrade. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you force user to update the latest version. I want to do the same

Comment: I am getting the store version of the app from my server and I am getting the current version of the app from the Constants.js file that has been added to project. This is the only way that I found for now. By the way, If you install the app from the ide, it is too diffucult to see the UPDATE options, because the special number of the app inside play store and the installed app from the ide is not the same.